# How to stop all code after Breaking nested loops

Tags: python, loops, try-catch, break

why an additional code execute after break from loop. I want to stop the code and modify some input, but the code continue after break and give me an Error.

```
if condition:
    for i in range(n):  
        if another condition:
            do_somthing
        else:
            flag = True
    
    for i in range(n: 
        if condition:
            do_something
        else:
            flag = True

    while flag:
        try:
            print('Erorr')
            break
        except:
            break
    # if break, I don't want to execute the rest of the code
    t = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        t.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Break does not stop the code, it breaks out of the loop. If you wish to stop the execution, you should raise an Exception instead.

If you still want to run some other stuff, but you want skip the part you commented, you can use an `else` statement.

```py
while flag:
    # do something here
else:
    # this will only be executed if the while does not break
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement

"""
A break statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the else clause’s suite. A continue statement executed in the first suite skips the rest of the suite and continues with the next item, or with the else clause if there is no next item.
"""

For example

```py
import random

flag = True
cnt  = 0
while flag:
    
    # do something here

    cnt += 1
    val = random.randint(0, 10)
    if val > 8:
        break

    if val < 2:
        raise Exception("Raised an exception")

    if cnt > 5:
        flag = False

else:
    # this will only be executed if the while does not break
    print("You ran the while loop more than 5 times")
```

Comment: Thanks, could you add an Exception to my code?

Comment: and I got 'NameError: name 'flag' is not defined'. I added flag as a global, but still get the same massage

Comment: could you add an Exception to stop the code only (I don't want to exit form it). Thank you

Comment: I added an example showing what I meant. I could not use your own code as your script has variables which I am not clear what they are.

Answer (score 1):

The `break` statement terminates the loop containing it (in this case - `try/except`.)

Control of the program flows to the statement immediately after the body of the loop.

If the `break` statement is inside a nested loop (loop inside another loop), the `break` statement will terminate the innermost loop.